# continuity and differentiability with piecewise functions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

I have a rather stupid question. I have a piecewise function

f(x, y) =
$x^3/(x^2+y^2)$ if (x, y) $!= (0, 0)$
if $(x, y) = (0, 0)$ then $f(x, y) = 0$

The question asks you to find the partial derivative of f(x, y) with respect to x at (0, 0). I have already calculated that this function is continuous at (0, 0). Do I use the f(x, y) = 0 as the function and get an answer of 0 or do I use the $f(x, y) = x^3/(x^2+y^2)$

and get the partial derivative of that and take the limit??

(**given that using the f(x, y) + x^3..... definition is correct)**
I calculated the partial derivative to be

$(3x^2(x^2+y^2)-2x(x^3))/(x^2+y^2)^2$

And using a limit calculator, the limit diverges. So is the partial derivative at (0, 0) DNE or 0?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The partial derivative that you obtain using normal derivative rules should not be expected to be valid at $(0,0)$ due to the singularity. Instead you need to use the limit definition. This will in fact give you a finite value in this problem. Actually, so would the expression you wrote, since you have $y$ fixed at zero throughout, so what you wrote reduces to $\frac{x^4}{x^4}$ on the $x$ axis.

Comment: So it is correct to use the f(x,y) != (0,0)?

Comment: For the $x$ partial at $(0,0)$ you need $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}$. This has nothing to do with it being piecewise. Where it being piecewise comes in is when you evaluate $f(h,0)$ (which isn't at $(0,0)$) and $f(0,0)$ (which is).

Comment: Ahh I see thank you